# Customizing Europe Lambert Conformal Conic to match the Mediterranean Basin extent

Tags: coordinate-system, mediterranean-sea

This is a follow-up question to [Which projection when dealing with least-cost path estimation across the Mediterranean area?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241184/which-projection-when-dealing-with-least-cost-path-estimation-across-the-mediter/241209?noredirect=1#comment376881_241209). The Europe Lambert Conformal Conic has been suggested by @Fezter.

Shall I customize the projection modifying the two standard parallels in order to best match my area of interest?

In fact, I am not interested in the whole Europe, rather in its southern-most part, i.e. the Mediterranean basin (let's say from Gibraltar to Cyprus [west-east], from Corsica to Lybia [north-south]).

Comment: That would reduce the overall distortion in the map/area of interest. One popular way is to place the standard parallel at 1/6 and 5/6 of the north-south extents.

Comment: Thank you @mkennedy for your comment. Would you mind to help me putting your suggestion to work? My N-S extent spans from 5127388 to 3247204 (in terms of y, UTM 33N), or 46.29230 to 29.35154 degrees N. How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to my own question, implementing what @mkennedy has kindly suggested. I used this website (http://www.geoplaner.com/) to get the latitute extent of my area of interest by getting the latitude of two points: **A** (*North*) 46 degrees N, **B** (*South*) 30 degrees N. The exent is 46-30=16 degrees. 16 divided by 6= 2.7. Therefore, the *Standard Parallel 1* (the southernmost) should be equal to 30+2.7= 32.7. The *Standard Parallel 2* (the northernmost) should be equal to 46-2.7= 44.7. I entered those Standard Parallel values into the relevant fields of the ArcMap's Europe Lambert Conformal Conic data window.